# Add text element to Google Chart

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, label, google-visualization

I'm using Google Charts (Javascript) to render some charts on my web application. Now I simply want to add a text label on a specific position on the chart (bottom right). For whatever reason there is nothing to be found on the internet about the subject.

An HTML overlay isn't gonna work as I also want the text to appear if I get the chart as an image with the following code:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    var imgUri = chart.getImageURI();
    $('#chart_img').attr('src', imgUri);
});
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/overlays#overview